# Shortcuts to foreach-if-else routine?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I wondered if there is any shortcut to routines likes this one:

```
foreach ($formFields as $field) {
    if(intval($field->getId()) === $number) {
        $label = $field->getLabel();
        $label = (strrchr($label, '*') === '*') ? substr($label, 0 , strlen($label) - 1) : $label;

        $dataFound = false;

        /** @var ParticipationData $data */
        foreach ($participationData as $data) {
            if($data->getFormField()->getId() == $field->getId()) {
                $text = str_replace($match, sprintf("%s<br/>%s", $label, $data->getValueData()), $text);
                $dataFound = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$dataFound) {
            $text = str_replace($match, sprintf("%s<br/>empty", $label), $text);
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

So the basic idea is that I want to check in the second foreach loop if `data` corresponds to `field` and if so replace some text.

After that loop I check via `dataFound` if the if condition was true and if not, I do someting different. I'd love to do something like this (second foreach loop):

```
foreach ($participationData as $data; $data->getFormField()->getId() == $field->getId()) {
    $text = str_replace($match, sprintf("%s<br/>%s", $label, $data->getValueData()), $text);

    break;
}
else {
    $text = str_replace($match, sprintf("%s<br/>empty", $label), $text);
}
```

So like a foreach loop with a condition. Is there such thing in PHP or JavaScript? Or how can I shortcut routines like that in a other way? Because I'm stumbling across these things pretty frequently.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but usually in cases like this I prefer to use `foreach (){ if (!condition) continue; ....}` This way you don't get a second very large and hard-to-follow indentation.

Comment: But this doesn't work, or does it? Because continue just skips the rest and continues with the next element in the array. But still I have to check in the end if the array contained an element that matched the condition and if not I do something else. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What I mean is that you're checking if the current item does _NOT_ match the condition you want, and if so - skips the rest of the block. This way you don't get double indentation for the entire block, but only 1 line that contains an `IF` and a `continue`. If it matches it - then the rest of the block will run.

Comment: Stick the foreach in a function and return when the data is found. Out side of the loop, return false